# Trouble filtering emails from group without affecting users in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I am trying to create a rule to filter Emails from a specific public group into a subfolder in my inbox.

I have tried:

```
#Absolutely does not work for my needs
Apply this rule after message arrives
From <people or public group>
move to <the specified> folder

#Does not work but I am not sure why
Apply this rule after message arrives
sent to <people or public group> #have tried group email, group name, and words in email or group
move to <the specified> folder
```

The first attempt filters everything from the group, including emails from users which is not desired.

The second attempt does nothing, though from what I have read it should work. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you set "and stop processing more rules" at the end, or whatever it's called? You may have a subsequent rule which then moves it somewhere else.

Comment: I did both with, and without that setting. The emails don't even leave the Inbox.

Comment: If you click 'Run rules now', does it work?

Comment: No, I did just receive a new email though (I was testing with previously received emails that I moved back to inbox), and the filter seemed to function correctly. I may just have to manually move the previous ones to correct folder.

Comment: If the rule is configured correctly, then 'run now' SHOULD move them... curious.

Comment: Email filtering based on other rules move no problem when using "run now", it seems to be specifically related to the "sent to <people or public group>" condition. For example, using the contents of the header, I don't seem to experience the same issue.

Comment: Please try the outlook rule condition of  "with specific words in the message header" and see if it could help.

Comment: @JeffYang7, I mentioned in my previous comment that the header works, I am wondering if there is a bug or something?

Comment: How did you add the users in the from condition? If you add them by manually typing, it is suggested to add them by selecting via your address book and see if the issue has any difference.